# Best port to connect Macbook Pro's USB C port to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi, displayport

What's the preferred external monitor port to connect a Macbook Pro with USB C ports only (a 2019 Macbook 16) if the monitor doesn't have USB C ports?

I read that USB C natively carries data in DisplayPort format so I'm wondering if that is the preferred port and whether using HDMI might involve some extra strain (and heat) on the Macbook. If yes, I would use a USB C to DisplayPort cable.

Comment: You would always use DisplayPort.  There is never a reason to use HDMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a USB-C to DisplayPort or USB-C to Mini-DisplayPort (depending on what ports are available on your monitor).

However, if you happen to have a USB-C to HDMI cable lying around, you can plug that in an check if it works for you. If it does work, there's no additional heat generated in the MacBook Pro or "strain" on the hardware.

Comment: You might find, though, that HDMI limits the resolution and/or refresh rate. (I got no more than 30Hz using a USB-C-to-HDMI cable, but 60Hz using USB-C-to-DisplayPort.)